# string fileName is returning `null`

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "studentID,Full_Name, DateOfBirth,MembershipID,Contact_Number,Emergency_Name,Emergency_Number,Expiry,Notes,ImagePath,ImageFile")] Student student)
    {
        if (student != null && student.ImageFile != null)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(student.ImageFile.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(student.ImageFile.FileName);
            fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
            student.ImagePath = "~/Image/" + fileName;
            fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Image/"), fileName);
            student.ImageFile.SaveAs(fileName);
        }

        db.Students.Add(student);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

my `string fileName` is returning `null` for some reason this was working but i updated the database after that it has been returning `null`
This is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Students", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
<h4>Student</h4>
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Student Image", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="file" name="ImageFile" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Not sure why this is happening as i rewrote the code again just to be sure but it is still returning `null`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in my Student Class 
I had

```
 public HttpPostedFile ImageFile { get; set; }
```

When i should've had

```
 public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }
```

silly error on my part